# Angular2 Input call twice a method

Tags: javascript, angular

why this code call twice the method 'addHero' ?

```
        @Component({
      selector: 'little-tour',
      template: `
        <input #newHero
          (keyup.enter)="addHero(newHero.value); newHero.value='' "
          (blur)="addHero(newHero.value); newHero.value='' ">
        <button (click)=addHero(newHero.value)>Add</button>
        <ul><li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero}}</li></ul>

        <p>{{pressed}}</p>
      `
    })
    export class LittleTourComponent {
        number = 1;
        pressed='';
      heroes = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];
      addHero(newHero: string) {
          if (newHero) {
            if (this.heroes.join('').indexOf(newHero) < 0) {
                this.heroes.push(newHero);
            }
            this.pressed+=' **(into IF)** ';
        }
        //newHero= " ";

        this.pressed+='pressed ' +this.number+', ';
        this.number++;
      }
    }
```

This is an example:

> **(into IF)** pressed 1, pressed 2, **(into IF)** pressed 3, pressed 4

Comment: What is "into IF"?

Comment: It would be called twice when you do what exactly?

Comment: the addHero() is called twice because of (blur). Why do want to addHero ob blur?

Comment: It was an example on official documentation:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html

Comment: "into IF" is just string for debugging

Comment: addHero  is called twice when i click the button for adding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three different ways on your code to call `addHero`:

- On enter key pressed while input is focused
- On input text blur (focus lost)
- On button click

Probably what you see is caused by the fact that `blur` on input text is executed when you click on button. I'd say you should remove `blur` handler since it conflicts with button click.

Answer (score 0):

use this , it should work fine

```
<input #newHero
          (keyup.enter)="test(newHero.value); newHero.value='' "
          (change)="test(newHero.value); newHero.value='' ">
```